# Is it valid for one person to answer a question twice?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

Some guy on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34016437/542251) has added two answers. Is this valid?

[image]

I queried:

> Why have you answered twice? Which one is correct?

to which he's responded:

> we can handle in both ways.

so I suppose he's saying both answers are correct.

The system allows you to do this and I think I've flagged something similar before and it got rejected.

But it feels a bit...grubby...to me. It feels like a mechanism to double your bonus.

Why do we allow this? Is this a valid usage of this feature?

Comment: "Valid"? Sure. Reasonable and useful? Not at all. They should have been in a single answer, with some *comparative analysis* explaining the difference between the two and when someone might choose one or the other. Not much you can do about that, though. Both are "answers", so there's no suitable flag. You just have to downvote.

Comment: @CodyGray: But what if a user doesn't know which of his solutions is better? In this case they might not be able do a comparative analysis. Posting two answers would at least allow the community to decide which one is better by voting. Is this also not useful at all?

Comment: The *correct* approach, @honk, would be for them to make that the subject of a new question. Voting is useful, but rather limited beyond basic ranking. If one of the solutions is terrible and one good, then voting works. But even then, votes don't explain *why* it is terrible, which is arguably the most important bit for all but copy-pastas. And in the more common case, where both solutions are good but have different applications/purposes, voting is useless because you'd conceivably upvote both. An answer is needed with explanation that compares and contrasts the two.